# Using different prediction models/algorithms for different subsets of dataset

Tags: predictive-models, data-mining

Is there practice in data mining and machine learning where different parts of dataset are predicted using different algorithms/models? The logic is that some data samples are better predicted with linear regression, for example, other with desicion tree based methods.

Answer (score 0):

This can best be addressed by the use of *ensemble classifier fusion* of a collection of classifiers (committee votes), such that one classifier may do better than another in certain regions of the data. Another approach is to employ boosting methods, which are applied to "weak" classifiers.  Boosted decision trees is an example.